# Почему не работает

Tags: c++

Проверка наличия цифры в строке

```cpp
if (pas.find('1') != string::npos) // так работает (в строке pas найдена цифра)
if (pas.find('1') = string::npos) // тут убираю (!)
```

Выдает ошибку (хотя по логике должно быть в строке pas не найдена цифра. Подскажите, почему так?

Comment: `=`  и `==` - это разные вещи.

Answer (score 4):

- `=` это операция присваивания значения
- `==` это операция сравнения

Ошибку же оно выдаёт потому что значение `string::npos` не к чему приравнивать, слева не пременная. Более того, код типа

```cpp
int a = 1, b = 2;
if (a=b) { std::cout << "hello"; }
```

Будет выводить в stdout "hello", потому что операция присваивания успешно выполнилась. И подобную ошибку достаточно сложно отловить, будьте внимательнее.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы перепутали оператор присваивания "=" с оператором сравнения "==".

В вашем случае нужно:

```
if (pas.find('1') == string::npos)
```